# Loading a geographical map in Python

Tags: python

I want to write a program that gets the geographical coordinates of a point, and then displays a map of some area around this point (for example a square that its center is the point and its side is R km) and saves it as an image file. Preferably, the map would also include streets names etc. What is the simplest, most straightforward way to do it? what package should I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally look for a web service instead of a Python package for this kind of complex tasks involving massive databases (read: MAPS).

Have a look at [OpenStreetMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/) or [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/) APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have the coordinates you could use something like matplotlib basemap:

http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html